# Add User Favorites option in google maps infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

How to implement user favorite option in google maps infowindow .For example. i want the same infowindow as http://hotpads.com/rentals/24276-Finely-Drive-Moreno-Valley-CA-92553--2w2hh5wwds7ce#lat=33.913198677411614&lon=-117.2406005859375&zoom=18&previewId=1x0ecwmx9ayrr&previewType=listing&heatmapIcons=true&dupeGrouping=building&listingTypes=rental,sublet,room,corporate&includeVaguePricing=false&loan=30,0.04,0&resultsPerQuad=24  ,but unable to get an idea of how to do it. Please give me a solution of implementing favorite option.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand whether you want code for infowindow html or algorithm for managing favourites...anyway Here is the code...but you have to modify it may be if you are iterating an array of markers...hope this helps you...

```
var favourites = [];

 var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
  '<ul id="myLinks">'+
      '<li><a href="javascript:" id="markerID" onclick="addRemoveFavourite(this);">add to favourites</a></li>'
  '</ul>'+
  '</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString,
  maxWidth: 200
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

function addRemoveFavourite(link){
    if(link.innerHTML == "add to favourites"){
        link.innerHTML = "remove from favourites";
        favourites.push(link.id);
    } else {
        link.innerHTML = "add to favourites";
        var index = favourites.indexOf(link.id);
        favourites.splice(index,1);
           }
}
```